# Two time steps in cocos2d project

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I'm trying to update the location of two different b2bodies, but they need to be in two different update methods to work. However, when I try to call the second method while the first is running, all of my b2bodies move out of place. I'm almost certain it is because there are 2 blocks of code like this `_world->Step(dt, velocityIterations, positionIterations);` in my project. Is there a way I can make sure these two blocks of code are specific for different b2bodies, and not the whole _world? Would creating another b2world mess up my collision detection between the two different bodies?

Comment: Why don't you call `_world->Step` only in main update cycle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. `Step` works on `world` level. The reason is that the movement of your body may affect other bodies  and it is worlds responsibility to manage this.

Also it looks very strange the you call `Step` while `Step` is already running. It makes no sense

Comment: Thanks! It was actually because I had put on gravity, so during the step function (the second one?) all the b2bodies would slowly move downwards. You still helped because if I move one of the step functions I can have it apply for all of the b2bodies.

Comment: @eeveeayen: You can set body inactive and it will be ignored in the simulation. (`body->SetActive(false`))